# Adjust Scroll Speed for Specific Application

Tags: mouse, macos

I recently bought my self an external mouse for my MacBook Pro Retina. It's great except I have one difficulty. In Safari and most apps the scroll speed is fine. But in some applications, the scroll speed is uncontrollable. Is there an app that lets me change the scroll speed for **specific applications** or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an app called [Smart Scroll](http://www.marcmoini.com/sx_en.html) which does what I need it to do. It allows you to change scroll speed for specific apps and a lot more options in general